# backbone-relational .set() method not updating related models

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-relational

I've got backbone-relational working fairly well so far.  I have relationships and reverse relationships well established (see below).  When I initially call `.fetch()` on my `Country` model instance, the `nominees` array is parsed out into `nominee` models perfectly.

When I call `.fetch()` again later, however, these related models do not update, even though the `nominee` data has changed (e.g. the vote count has incremented).  Essentially it seems that Backbone's `.set()` method understands relationships initially but not subsequently.

**Country Model**

```
var Country = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend({

    baseUrl : config.service.url + '/country',

    url : function () {
        return this.baseUrl;
    },

    relations : [
        {
            type : Backbone.HasMany,
            key : 'nominees',
            relatedModel : Nominee,
            collectionType : Nominee_Collection,
            reverseRelation : {
                key : 'country',
                includeInJSON : false
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

**JSON Response on `country.fetch()`**

```
{
  "entrant_count" : 1234,
  "vote_count" : 1234,
  "nominees" : [
    {
      "id" : 3,
      "name" : "John Doe",
      "vote_count" : 1,
      "user_can_vote" : true
    },
    {
      "id" : 4,
      "name" : "Marty McFly",
      "vote_count" : 2,
      "user_can_vote" : true
    }
  ]
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it appears that backbone-relational specifically forgoes updating relations automatically (see the `updateRelations` method), and simply emits a `relational:change:nominees` event which your models can target.  If, however, you wish to programmatically update your related models, simply modify the `updateRelations` method as follows:

```
Backbone.RelationalModel.prototype.updateRelations = function( options ) {
    if ( this._isInitialized && !this.isLocked() ) {
        _.each( this._relations || [], function( rel ) {
            // Update from data in `rel.keySource` if set, or `rel.key` otherwise
            var val = this.attributes[ rel.keySource ] || this.attributes[ rel.key ];

            if ( rel.related !== val ) {
                this.trigger( 'relational:change:' + rel.key, this, val, options || {} );

                // automatically update related models
                _.each(val, function (data) {                           
                    var model = rel.related.get(data.id);
                    if (model) {
                        model.set(data);
                    } else {
                        rel.related.add(data);
                    }
                });
            }
        }, this );
    }
};
```

(Note that this does not handle deletion of models from a collection, only updates to existing models, and the addition of new models to a collection)